# How do I match this regex

Tags: regex

I need to match this pattern: `Var0Pt0` where the first digit will range from 0-9 and the second digit will be one of 0,2,7. The letters are constant. Any idea?

It should match just the word exactly not say `abcVar0Pt0bbs`

`(Var\dPt\d)` doesn't seem to be it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a [**character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) for the second digit, and use anchors:

```
^Var\dPt[027]$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/saRnLi/1).

The `[027]` match either `0`, `2` or `7`, and `^` anchors the match at the start of the string, and `$` anchors the match at the string end.

Comment: And depending on whether the regex implementation is good (i.e. Unicode-aware) or not, you may want to expand `\d` to `[0-9]` to avoid accidentally matching a lot more.

Comment: @Joey: In JS, `\d` = `[0-9]`. In Java, without `(?U)` UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS flag, `\d` = `[0-9]`. In Python, without `re.UNICODE`, `\d` = `[0-9]`. In PHP, without `/u` modifier, `\d` = `[0-9]`.  If the regex is to be used in .NET, that is not necessary, `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` flag will do that. In Python 3.x, [`re.A`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.A) should deal with this. If it is to be used outside coding environment, yes, `\d` is better replaced with `[0-9]`.

Comment: Wiktor: It's just that I prefer things to be explicit most of the time and since they didn't ask for a specific regex implementation I'm fairly sure they have no idea that there _can_ be differences, that's why I pointed it out. Granted, things like `\w` and `\b` are much, much worse (although not relevant here).

Comment: I used `\d` because it was used in the original pattern (so, I surmised it is not a regex flavor like MySQL or Bash that do not support `\d` shorthand character class). (Just checked, [Ruby also treats `\d` as `[0-9]`](http://ideone.com/4fcTYt))